# How to disable case sensitivity in Linux environment

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, database-schema

I'm using a MySQL schema created on Windows machine on an Ubuntu box. But when my application tries to access db I get a

`Table 'schema.Booking' doesn't exist`

How do I disable this to make the sproc case insensitive?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165944/how-to-change-mysql-table-names-in-linux-server-to-be-case-insensitive

Comment: Your application is written in.... which language?

Answer (score 0):

> Use lower_case_table_names=0 on Unix and lower_case_table_names=2 on Windows. This preserves the lettercase of database and table names. The disadvantage of this is that you must ensure that your statements always refer to your database and table names with the correct lettercase on Windows. If you transfer your statements to Unix, where lettercase is significant, they do not work if the lettercase is incorrect.

See : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html