# How to ignore case sensitivity in SQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I wrote code in PHP using SQL queries.

I have a MySQL database (using a xamp server for windows) named `mydatabase`. It is in lower case, table names are also lower case.

I did use some queries in PHP like the following

```
SELECT * FROM BRANCHPARAMETERES
```

(Actually, the mysql database itself contains a table named branchparameters)

I migrated code like this into linux using a lamp server.

I am facing problem of queries case sensetivity while running page in linux.

How can i solve this one time?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165944/how-to-change-mysql-table-names-in-linux-server-to-be-case-insensitive

Answer (score 0):

Just try this [**strtolower**](https://www.php.net/strtolower)

```
<?php
echo $tablename = strtolower('BRANCHPARAMETERES');
echo "SELECT * FROM ".$tablename;
?>
```

Just Different Method